# eval array value bash

Tags: arrays, bash, eval

I am trying to substitute both the array name and value using eval and losing my mind with combinations that are not working

```
 $ eval echo \$${port[$index]}${item[0]}${item[8]}
   some_value
```

---

```
declare -a port=('Ex' 'backup' 'DRAC' 'Service');
declare -a item=('net' 'switch' 'port' 'speed' 'cvsswitch' 'vlan' 'link' 'count' 'list')

       for x in $(eval echo \$${port[$index]}${item[0]}${item[8]}) ; do
           eval ${port[$index]}${item[7]}=$[${port[$index]}${item[7]} +1]                                      # incriment count
           eval echo \$${port[$index]}${item[7]}                                                               # set count
           eval \$"${port[$index]}${item[1]}"[\$${port[$index]}${item[7]}]   <---- not working
       done
fi
```

---

### I am getting the following output when trying to eval this statement to assign the array[index_value] a value.

```
$ eval \$${port[$index]}${item[1]}[\$${port[$index]}${item[7]}]=abc123
-bash: [1]: command not found
or
$ eval \$${port[$index]}${item[1]}[\$${port[$index]}${item[7]}]=abc123
-bash: [1]=abc123: command not found
```

---

Does anyone have advice on how to get this working?

Thanks!

Comment: What if we stop talking about eval, and ask clearly about the thing you're trying to accomplish, rather than the tool you want to do it with?

Comment: For instance, when you say `eval \$${port[$index]}${item[1]}[\$${port[$index]}${item[7]}]=abc123` -- what, exactly, do you expect that to actually *do*?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need eval, and shouldn't use eval, for assignments of this type.

```
declare -a port=('Ex' 'backup' 'DRAC' 'Service')
declare -a item=('net' 'switch' 'port' 'speed' 'cvsswitch' 'vlan' 'link' 'count' 'list')

index=3 # for example
array_name=${port[$index]}${item[1]}
array_idx=${port[$index]}${item[7]}

declare -A "$array_name" # since your index is non-numeric
printf -v "${array_name}[${array_idx}]" '%s' abc123
```

This will set `Serviceswitch[Servicecount]` to `abc123`.

Assigning your variable names ahead-of-time is better practice anyhow -- makes it easier to diagnose why something failed when you can look at the pieces that built up to it.

See [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) for an exhaustive treatment of the subject, including portability discussion.